# Run python code from a windows .bat file

Tags: python, batch-file

I want to launch my python application from a bat file, e.g. "my_app.bat", using python code. The code I want to execute would like the following:

```
from my_apps import my_app
import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_app.main(sys.argv[1:])
```

How can I execute the above piece of code from a bat file?

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been looking around and found [this](https://gist.github.com/jadient/9849314)

If you add this line you run the python code inside the bat file as if it was a .py file:

```
@echo off & python -x "%~f0" %* & goto :eof
```

the example looks like :

```
@echo off & python -x "%~f0" %* & goto :eof
from my_apps import my_app
import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_app.main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Answer (score 3):

**C:\code\cmd\my_app.py**

```
#from my_apps import my_app
import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(sys.argv[1:])
```

**C:\code\cmd\my_app.bat**

```
@echo off
C:\Python34\python.exe -u "C:\code\cmd\my_app.py" %*
```

Usage:

```
C:\Users\Cees.Timmerman>my_app 1 2 3
['1', '2', '3']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this idd works. The solution i found on the web effectively makes your bat file behave like a .py file